# Is it possilbe to initialize array in class with MSVS2017 C++ compiler without getting error C2864?

Tags: c++

Why does VS2017 C++ compiler report `error C2864: a static data member with an in-class initializer must have non-volatile const integral type or be specified as 'inline'` for the below?   Is there anyway to initialize within the class instead of having to put it in the `.cpp` module?  Even better, be able to initialize with [] instead of [3]?

```
class CTest
{
public:

  static const uint32_t Val1=1;
  static const uint32_t Val2=2;
  static const uint32_t Val3=3;

  struct sTestStruct
  {
    const uint32_t Val;
    const TCHAR *String;
  };

  static const sTestStruct s_arrMyValToString[3]={
    { Val1, _T("A Str") },
    { Val2, _T("B Str") },
    { Val3, _T("C Str") }
  };

};
```

TIA!!

Comment: The important bits of the duplicate answer are `inline constexpr`.

Comment: Wasn't really a duplicate, but found the way to define it by trial and error to make VS2017 happy: `constexpr static const sTestStruct s_arrMyValToString`